# Как запросить Emai у пользователяl c помощью Вконтакте API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите пожалуйста, как используя VK SDK получить email пользователя.

**UPD**

На сколько я понял, при соответствующих правах, email приходит в aссessToken а вот как его перехватить?

Comment: ознакомьтесь с данным вопросом, может поможет [Как получить email через API ВКонтакте](https://toster.ru/q/94065)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, спустя несколько часов мучений я разобрал половину VK SDK и понял как запрашивать емеил.
Для начала, логично нужно просить права на этот емаил, поэтому добавьте VKScope.EMAIL. (не обращайте внимание что он пока подчеркнут)

```
private List<string> _scope = new List<string> { VKScope.WALL, VKScope.EMAIL };
```

Далее переходим в класс VKScope. Там вначале перечисление различных прав которые мы можем запросить. Аналогично добавьте туда емаил.

```
    public const String EMAIL = "email"; //эту строчку
    public const String OFFLINE = "offline";
    public const String NOHTTPS = "nohttps";
    public const String DIRECT = "direct";
```

Далее переходим в класс VKAccessToken Там везде где есть что-то связанное с UserId точно так же во все функции добавляем Email

```
    public const String USER_ID = "user_id";
    public const string EMAIL = "email";
    public String UserId = null;
    public String Email = null;
```

_

```
protected String SerializeTokenData()
    {
        var args = new Dictionary<String, Object>
        {
            {ACCESS_TOKEN, AccessToken},
            {EXPIRES_IN, ExpiresIn},
            {USER_ID, UserId},
            {EMAIL, Email},  //...
```

_

```
public static VKAccessToken TokenFromParameters(Dictionary<String, String> args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Count == 0)
            return null;

        try
        {
            var token = new VKAccessToken();
            args.TryGetValue(ACCESS_TOKEN, out token.AccessToken);

            string expiresValue;
            args.TryGetValue(EXPIRES_IN, out expiresValue);
            int.TryParse(expiresValue, out token.ExpiresIn);

            args.TryGetValue(USER_ID, out token.UserId);
            args.TryGetValue(EMAIL, out token.Email); //...
```

На этот исправления VK SDK заканчиваются, осталось после того как пользователь авторизируется через ВК запросить емеил

```
var MyEmail = VKSDK.GetAccessToken();
            string email = MyEmail.Email;
```

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь помог :)